# JSONObject catch exception

Tags: android, json

Dears Im new in Android , I have a problem in Json here is my code... i debug it , everything is good but it jumped to the catch block when reaching this statment

```
jArray = new JSONObject(result);
```

so its return null...

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

      //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        try{

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what in result String

Comment: plz post our json string you are getting from server

Comment: print the string result, and paste here.

Comment: this is the result [{"CompletionStatus":2,"ContactMobile":"962799407083","ContactPerson":"William Erwin","Description":" AS AS AS AS ","Details":"Testy CCCC","ScheduledDate":"\/Date(1356901200000+0300)\/","WorkOrderID":206}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse as shown below

```
JSONObject mainJSON = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray jsonMainArr = mainJSON.getJSONArray("result");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.toArray().length; i++) {
        JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
        String CompletionStatus= childJSONObject.getString("CompletionStatus");
        String ContactMobile= childJSONObject.getString("ContactMobile");
    }
```

hope this ll help you out.

Answer (score 2):

replace this because JSONObject is not converted to JSONArray

```
 jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you need an Array not an Object for your JSON.

try:

```
jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

not

```
jArray = new JSONObject(result);
```

Log your error like this:

```
 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data ", e);
```

and you will get a more detailed description of what and where your problem is

[Json Array API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Answer (score 0):

log out your result, before parse it to check whether is a valid json string or not, perhaps not

Answer (score 0):

If Your Sring starts with these brackets

```
 [ ]
```

then Use `JSONArray` or

if String Starts with these brackets `{}` Then `JSONObject` Should Use.

I thinks this the region otherwise response is not comming then Try in place of

```
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
```

Replace

```
HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
```

Comment: my service is HttpGet, not post, I'll try JsonArray, i have some problems in understanding how to parse Json could you help me in finding a tips for that... I'll be thankful :)

Comment: Sometimes HttpGet not work But in Your case its working..
For Checking that JsonFormate is right just use Jsonlint.com &
it will parse from jArray = new JSONArray(result);